# why java.net.HttpURLConnection responsed unidentified characters?

Tags: java, web-services

My request executor class gives unidentified characters as response. please help me to sort out this

**import java.net.HttpURLConnection;**

```
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) neturl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");//ADDED
```

===here I do my some additions & logics ==

```
        statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

===here I do my some additions & logics.response code is **200** but response text not shows as correctly==

```
        if ((statusCode == 200) || (statusCode == 201) || (statusCode == 302)) {

           is = connection.getInputStream();
        }
        else {
            is = connection.getErrorStream();
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            retStr += output;
        }
```

this is my response [retStr]

> }Umo�6�l���>�    `I�׬Y+��ك��b����D"U���/��;J�_�$�B�w���'7�����cHM�����v��,6��R�����/�����|�O��؃�Ԙ��WU�UZ�=�Vg0�2�Y��jTkL����f<F�Q�I��%����,�    *:F,��Q��T�K}�N���:gjp�6
>   ��R�e�ca��2/2�D�Pq��m�G����a��H����P���9��T��~�^�'�Kdk�;��֠�[�&m��%fq�XR[)$łn�7\���Z.M�BµQ<*i�C�2#�(TL��!�;��h�)����n�G��h��s���z:�  �tB��0����pr��@�E�P���m)�0G<"��5!˸��/yL��U�V+�F%�!(P�\�Tj"�P5��0c����-��î�j��±�Zr4���)�f��f�^Y��&��tT����X)��9݂lV]�����׽��T1č��P5��,��&+�ũ�9.�.m�5Ǫ��
>   *��t���|r�M�rL    f��c����u�xas`�#g�:��On��PՁ�_�q���%a4�E��~$���a��s�щC%���"�kA�$ƍƋb��/!3������b����%c5����/����:�i���%�罺���o�貰��Q�s�6G�~o�5���]��o+��{��0��g輀}�V�ڸ�;�ﱙ#�7[�D�|�����L6�v���!�要ce�\��g�t�!�Ia�^��G�h�Hfk���Zr$R�j�Nu��[�\�u+��gr%�\�m�[N;���}�ӳ��2�l����ׯgKa�������ؼ"j�������xBpn6����+��/��G�L�*F���R����yBf��N�����ڜZ�킏��i�J�%M�Cۉހ����n�;*�G��7m���m;�����)�a�X��'�ћ�l@�GTi$���C��Vf���v��$�Z��93q����ߚ�H�Je�k�t�����+��?��ilb�RAu�.��* �9B^��(�)����

Comment: what is url ? i suspect its `https`

Comment: What was the response code?

Comment: @AmeyJadiye : Yes dear Amey.its https url

Comment: @EJP : response code is 200 & below mentioned that unidentified response String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting gzip stream as output here .. try below things in your code.

When you call `https` URL you get `HttpsURLConnection` as return which dont handle gzip streamsso try below.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
...
InputStream inStream = new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```